# Get only records related to only currently logged in user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Any ideas about how to approach it?

Let's say there are 100 records

A) One user should get only 50 and other all of them

B) User should get only records that he created

Is there already some option built into spring boot? or I have to add the "permission" field and filter it using currently logged in user in Backend?

It cannot be like that someone will provide the different user in the query string and he will get records for other users

Answer (score 0):

Spring / Spring Boot helps you to know who is the currently logged in user and what permissions he has. But the logic which permission what means needs to be implemented by the application, i.e. you have to implement it.